# In which episode of The Simpsons did this animation error occur?

Tags: identify-this-episode, the-simpsons, production-mistakes

I'm looking for an episode where **a black faceless man** stands behind Homer in his home.

This due to an animation error. (E.g. Like in the episode with Mel Gibson where [Homer has a "third hand"](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-chYsKgDhCZM/UBfVYH16hGI/AAAAAAAAAA0/X6KF1MwlCwM/s1600/4923701bscap00001121212.jpg)).

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site! Do you have any more details about the story in that episode? It might help someone to identify it. Was it an old episode, or new? Anything extra you can think of can help.

Comment: There are more than 600 episodes of The Simpsons. I would need a season atleast. Also, consider adding a descriptive title and as much detail as you can, even where and what year you watched it.

Comment: It's probably from one of the first few seasons, they had a lot of animation mistakes. I don't have episodes on my computer any more but I'll check my DVDs later.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe the episode you are looking for is **Homer Vs. Lisa and the 8th Commandment** from Season 2, at time 19:40 on my DVD.

But I don't think it's an animation mistake per se - Homer is at the window and the other characters are in the background so are meant to look out of focus and "blurry". Well, judge for yourself :)

[image: Homer Simpson]

Comment: Looks like Mr Burns, Apu, and two others?

Comment: Yes it's Burns, Smithers, Apu and I think Lenny. Here's a screenshot of who's in the room at that point: http://simpsoncrazy.com/content/screenshots/episodes/7f13/7f13_028.jpg

Comment: It might be worth adding the linked picture into your answer, to put the current image into context? Well done on finding that btw, on very little information!